# Firefox on Linux always shows history dropdown when clicking back button

Tags: windows-7, linux, firefox, ubuntu-14.04

When I left-click on the back button in Firefox on Linux, I go back 1 page and then a dropdown with my browsing hisrory appears. Always. And then I have to click some place else to make it go away.

On Windows, same Firefox version, I only go back and there is no history drop down. Just like I want it.

Is there some config switch to avoid the drop-down? Anything else I can check?

I'm using Firefox 44.0.2 on Linux and Windows, but its been like this for a while now.

Comment: What happens if you start firefox in safe mode (run `firefox -safe-mode` from terminal)

Comment: Better! Turns out this is a side effect of the "Clear History" Add-on which should only add a "Clear History" button, but seems to have side effects.

Comment: Sweet. You can use Ctrl-Shift-Del to bring up the clear history dialog if you don't want to have the add-on active.

Comment: Excelent! Is there a way to create a custom button in the menu for that ? I'm not so good remembering keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: This looks like it will do what you're looking for: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/privacy-forget-button-firefox-browsing-history